# Access Azure blob storage in Amazon EMR

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, azure-blob-storage, amazon-emr

I have a large volume of data (~20 TB) in Azure blob storage that I want to access from Spark cluster setup in Amazon EMR. What is the best way to do this? Is transferring this data to S3 the only option? If yes, what is the cheapest way to transfer this data to S3?

Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Based on your description, you have about 20TB data want to transfer to Amazon S3. I am not familiar with Amazon. But in Azure we will be charged for the data transfer. Here is the [pricing site](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-transfers/). For example you need $0.08 per GB. 20*1024*0.08= $1638.4. It is very expensive. I would suggest you to consider other approaches. If you do not care about money at all, please try to search tool in google or write your own code to transfer these data.